# Mechanize pre/post connect hooks

Tags: ruby, mechanize, mechanize-ruby

Using Mechanize, I need to find some way to limit requests to 1 per second(or 1 every 5 seconds, or 2 every minute, etc the point is find some way to rate limit requests).

Searching, this seems to be the way to begin to approach the issue: pre/post connect hooks. Only I don't exactly know what to do with them or how to approach, I'm guessing from my level and research I need to do a lambda or proc that says 'hey wait a second', seems basic enough.

My question is basically for an example or another clue on how to do this. I tried several lambdas(and I'm at a low level of understanding in what exactly this would do):

```
@agent.pre_connect_hooks << lambda { |pc| sleep 1 }
```

but this just turns my requests to errors:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)
```

Even beginning to go through the mechanize code yields little for me so far.

Any input and learning guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Proc` instead :

`@agent.pre_connect_hooks << Proc.new { sleep 1 }`

Comment: Yeah that works, not sure why I was stuck on doing a lambda, but that is a simple start.

Answer (score 4):

Your lambda needs 2 arguments:

```
agent.pre_connect_hooks << lambda do |agent, request|
  sleep 1
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also pass a `Method`:

```
def my_pre_hook(agent, request)
  # Do fun stuff.
end

agent.pre_connect_hooks << method(:my_pre_hook)
```